# Recieving 'null' values from a jsp page into Struts 2 Action

Tags: java, struts2

I have a jsp page and struts 2 Action class . When I submit  the form in the jsp , I am getting null values into the action.

The JSP code looks like :

```
   <s:form id="user" name="user" action="initUserAdmin">

    <s:textfield name="userName"  cssClass="txtbox" size="30" />
    <div class="btn"><a href='<s:url action="searchUserAdmin"/>' 
    title="Search"    id="button" class="btn" ><span>Search</span></a></div>

   </s:form>
```

The struts.xml has this part

```
      <action name="*UserAdmin" method="{1}" class="com.mphasis.im.web.action.UserAction">
        <result name="init" type="tiles">user</result>
        <result name="search" type="tiles">user</result>
        <result name="reset" type="tiles">user</result>
        <result name="createNew" type="tiles">createNewUser</result>
    </action>
```

And the Action class has this :

```
        public class UserAction extends BaseAction
          {
            public String userName;

        public String getUserName()
        {
      return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName)
        {
      this.userName = userName;
        }

            public String search()
           {
            searchProcessed = true;

            System.out.println("******** inside search ******");

            System.out.println("username = "+ userName);

            return TilesConstants.SEARCH;
           }
```

And the output comes as below when I type  a string in the text box in jsp page.

```
        ******** inside search ******
         username = null
```

What might be the problem ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href='<s:url action="searchUserAdmin"/>' 
title="Search"    id="button" class="btn" >
```

It's just a href to the URL of action and with no parameter. Therefore, the 'userName' in the action is null.

Comment: Hi Thanks . In my scenario , I want the userName in the class to be populated by using struts2 itself when I submit the jsp . How can we achieve that ? .   I have edited my post to include <s:form > tag and a part of struts.xml .

Comment: @vinoth: Try using <s:submit> instead of <a href> in the form.

Comment: Yeah . I tried that. It works . The problem is we want the look and feel of buttons. So I think , I must use a javascript to submit the form ..is that right ?

Comment: @vinoth: Just check the document. Maybe this can work. <s:submit cssClass="btn"> or <s:submit type="button" cssClass="btn">

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:form id="user" name="user" action="initUserAdmin">

    <s:textfield name="userName"  cssClass="txtbox" size="30" />
    <div class="btn"><a href='javascript:submitme()' 
    title="Search"    id="button" class="btn" ><span>Search</span></a></div>

   </s:form>
```

Javascript

```
function submitme(){
document.user.submit()
}
```

Also in the action mapping you provided the action name you are using there is `UserAdmin` whereas in the form action you are using `initUserAdmin`.They must be the same